# Jackson subclass override field

Tags: java, jackson

I have 2 classes

```
public class A {
    protected String id;
}
```

And

```
public class B extends A {
    private String bval;
}
```

The JSON we recieve for class B has the id with a different name, is there are way to tell jackson to use a different property name for id in classB than in classA?

Comment: the variable is probably declared as `protected`

Answer (score 0):

Obe way to do it is to use the "any setter" feature, where Jackson is told to call a method for all "unknown" properties.  You can then do the assignment yourself:

```
public class B extends A {

  // all unknown properties will go here
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setUnknownProperty(String key, Object value) {
      if (key.equals("anotherNameForId")) {
          id = (String)value;
      }
  }
```

Comment: That is a good idea, I found a solution that is slightly lighter

Answer (score 0):

I was using lombok

```
@Getter(onMethod = @__( @JsonProperty("id")))
```

and in class B

```
@Override
@JsonProperty("bID")
public String getId(){
    return this.id;
}
```

Comment: I thought you said you receive json, which means setter is called ?

Comment: Yes we do recieve JSON but jackson can use annotations on the getter for the field